# How to write and propose an RFC?

Tags: rfc

I found that IMAPv4 has a shortcoming as it forces users to download whole body (text/HTML + attachments).

How to write and propose an RFC to address the issue?

Please kindly share if you had experience of previously writing technical documents, proposals, especially RFCs.

Comment: Individual sections of a body can be specified by parameters to the FETCH of a BODY. You can even fetch a partial section of a body based on an octet range. What extra functionality are you actually proposing?

Comment: i don't think that imap *forces users to download whole body* (what for, by the way?). my imap client at least can happily download headers only, and i cannot find anything to that effect in the spec (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html ). what makes you think so?

Comment: Well, you can find from http://www.coderanch.com/t/475359/Other-JSE-JEE-APIs/java/IMAP-javax-mail-Fetching-Only & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301213/how-to-efficiently-parse-emails-without-touching-attachments-using-python

Comment: I've made an mvp for writing rfc's on getrfcs.com, it's still in it's infancy but it should to the work. tnx Tom

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There's actually an RFC for that: [RFC 7322 - RFC Style Guide](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7322).

Comment: [**RFC 7322**, RFC Style Guide](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7322) now supersedes 2223.

Answer (score 8):

The responses by Jörg W Mittag and Darin Dimitrov are perfectly correct but they forget to add that writing a RFC and having it adopted is a **long** process which requires time, dedication, a hard technical work and a lot of social interactions.

Comment: +1 thanks for the input :) I didn't know that there are lots of social interactions that need to happen.

Comment: For these interactions, RFC 4677 is a good start, more realistic than RFC 2223.

Answer (score 5):

This is both an answer and a further question.
Given that writing an RFC "requires time, dedication, a hard technical work and a lot of social interactions", wouldn't a good idea be to talk about it with other knowledgeable people before doing all that, possibly in vain?

I think that the correct place to do that is on the "IETF (Internet Engineering Task Force) mailing list" isn't it?
(I once participated in IETF discussions amounting to say "How can I correctly write my name André?" (it was the joke at that time but the general project succeeded extremely well with UTF8 (which is just an encoding but that became the synonym of the universal character code ISO 10646 because it is unique))).

So, I wonder why the first topic of RFC 7322 et al. is not "how to start preliminary discussions (recommended)".